# T-sql compare two variables see if the other one holds the first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen this question but not asked like this, if there is a question like please link it.

I'm using T-SQL and I'm writing a stored procedure.

So I have a `@masterstring` let's say

```
'www.apple.com'
```

and a `@slavestring`

```
'www.apple.com/subdirectory'
```

I use the code below to see if I should add rows to the database.

What I want to do is to add rows to the database if it passes this clause.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ranking_date, ranking_keyword, ranking_id_doman
                FROM [dbo].[t_ranking] 
                WHERE ranking_id_doman = @domanID
                AND ranking_keyword = @keyword
                AND ranking_searchesincluded = @searchesincluded) 
                AND @masterstring like @slavestring +'%'
```

`@masterstring` stays the same through the whole process, but `@slavestring` changes for every insert I do.

QUESTION
How do I write the AND statement so that every `@slavestring` that contains the `@masterstring` will be true?

I have tried with

Attempt #1:

```
AND @masterstring like '%' + @slavestring + '%'
```

Attempt #2:

```
@masterstring like @slavestring + '%'
```

None of them work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `LEN` functions to do this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ranking_date, ranking_keyword, ranking_id_doman
               FROM [dbo].[t_ranking] 
               WHERE ranking_id_doman = @domanID
               AND ranking_keyword = @keyword
               AND ranking_searchesincluded = @searchesincluded) 
               AND SUBSTRING(@slavestring, 1, LEN(@masterstring)) = @masterstring
```